# How to dynamically include object value based on condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is my objects

```
{"seatName": seats[i].name,
             "fare": seats[i].fare,
             "passenger": [{
                  "name":"",
                  "gender": "",
               // "email":this.props.authStore.email,
               // "mobile": this.props.authStore.phone
             }]
           }
```

Here, i need to include

```
"email":this.props.authStore.email,
"mobile": this.props.authStore.phone
```

When (i === 0), other than 0, for other these value should not be included ! How to achieve this ?

I tried like this :

```
(i === 0) ? "email": (i === 0) ? this.state.primaryUserEmail : "",
```

But it throws error !

Comment: `"email": (i === 0) ? this.state.primaryUserEmail :null` would be enough

Comment: Email should not be null, in other words ! It should not be in the object

Comment: assuming `data` as the main object `i===0 && (data.passenger[0].email = "test@email.com");` use like this after the main object initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :

```
...(i === 0 && {email: this.props.authStore.email}),
```

It will include when conditions satisfied and removes when not !

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {"seatName": "Joe",
             "fare": 12,
             "passenger": [{
                  "name":"",
                  "gender": "",
               // "email":this.props.authStore.email,
               // "mobile": this.props.authStore.phone
             }]
           }

/*
you can simply check if that passenger object has an email and mobile number and if they don't have you can then assign the number and email.


*/

if(!data.passenger[0]["email"]){
  data.passenger[0]["email"] = "test@email.com";
}

if(!data.passenger[0]["mobile"]){
  data.passenger[0]["mobile"] = 1234567890;
}

console.log(data)

/*
OUTPUT:
{
  seatName: 'Joe',
  fare: 12,
  passenger: [ { name: '', gender: '', email: "test.email.com", mobile: 1234567890 } ]
}
*/
```